# How to write alias in Django QuerySets?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

How can one write an alias for the column name in django query set.
Would be useful for union-style combinations of two linked field to the same foreign model (for instance).

for example in mysql :

```
select m as n, b as a from xyz
```

how can i do this in django query set ?

```
models.Table.objects.all().values('m', 'b')
```

Any help really appreciate it.

Comment: I'd be really surprised it that were possible. The difference in Django versus plain SQL is that the fields map up to fields on Model in Django whereas there's no constraint on the names that come back for SQL. Even if you could alias the field name, that would break functionality in your Model.

Comment: why i got this requirement because, doing query from two tables using ORM in that i have got a output , as a = [{name: 'ab', am: 'xy'}, {a_name: 'ab', pm: 'mm'}]. here name and a_name as same value but key different, so i taught if i make field value alias then i can get {name: 'ab', pm: 'mm'}

Answer (score 22):

You can annotate the fields as you want, with the [F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F):

```
from django.db.models import F

models.Table.objects.all().values('m', 'b').annotate(n=F('m'), a=F('b'))
```

Answer (score 8):

Although this could have been done before by using `extra(select={'n':'m','a':'b'})`, I agree that this really should have been a part of `values()` itself.

To that end, and inspired by Alex's ticket, I have [just posted](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16735#comment:2) a [patch](https://code.djangoproject.com/attachment/ticket/16735/column_alias.diff) that adds this feature.  I hope you'll find it useful!

Comment: Looks like extra doesnt work like mentioned above with values in django 1.4

Comment: Has the patch actually ever made it to prod?

Answer (score 5):

Your reason in the comment makes no sense. Each field in the model has its own column in the database, and there's never any danger of mixing them up. You can of course tell a field to use a column name that's different from the field name:

```
myfield = models.CharField(max_length=10, db_column='differentname')
```

but I don't know if that will help you, because I still don't know what your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm presuming this isn't possible, so I've raised a ticket for the feature to be added, I think there is some merit to being able to do this. Please see the ticket for more information.

https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16735

Answer (score 1):

**you can also use .alias() in your queryset.**

```py
.alias(alias=SomeExpression()).annotate(                     
    SomeOtherExpression('alias'))
```

```py
.alias(alias=SomeExpression()).order_by('alias')
```

```py
.alias(alias=SomeExpression()).update(field=F('alias'))
```

for your specific case, this would be the answer

```py
models.Table.objects.all().alias(
    n=F('m'), a=F('b')).values('m', 'a')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I really can't understand what you are trying to do however it sounds like what you are looking for is the [extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#extra) queryset method.  This for most purposes acts in the same manner as AS does in sql.