# "SELECT field as x..." with Django ORM

Tags: django, orm

Is it possible to use AS sql statement with Django ORM:

`SELECT my_field AS something_shiny WHERE my_condition = 1`

If it is possible then how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [django : How to write alias in queryset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6833843/django-how-to-write-alias-in-queryset) - See my answer to that question; I proposed a patch that adds this behavior to `values`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use [extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra)

```
Foo.objects.filter(cond=1).extra(select={'sth_shiny':'my_field'})
```

Then you could access `sth_shiny` attr of resulted Foo instances

Comment: This is especially useful (over the F approach) for renaming fields to 'id' so Django doesn't give "ValueError: The annotation 'id' conflicts with a field on the model.".  I needed to do this so I could select a field as id.

Answer (score 26):

By now the Django documentation says that one should [use extra as a last resort](http://django.readthedocs.io/en/1.9.x/ref/models/querysets.html#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra).

So here is a better way to do this query:

```
from django.db.models import F
Foo.objects.filter(cond=1).annotate(sth_shiny=F('my_field'))
```